# How to highlight region in a image?

Tags: android, image

I was playing with an app that uses a facebook-style method for helping the use select square size profile pictures. Here's a screenshot: [image]

Now I'm curious to know how they implemented this. Do they use a single image, and then dynamically highlight the region when the square is moved over the image? Or do they use two images, one on top of the other, and render the right region when the square is moved? If the former is possible, how can this be done? I guess an alpha value was added to the bottom image, but if so, how can you cancel it with the top view, hence highlighting the region?

Thanks!

Comment: I would personally guess it's a `Canvas` with an image painted onto it then a set of four dark rectangles drawn (or perhaps a more efficient method with a mask?) to make the dark area, and finally an orange rectangle on top.

Comment: why the four rectangles? wouldn't one black rectangle suffice? and how do you get the orange rectangle without the dark?

Comment: Unless you masked out the area in the middle, or drew over it, you'd want four dark rectangles to go around it. (Imagine a column of black on either side, then one on the top, and one on the bottom. Four rectangles, and a hold in the middle.)

Comment: the 4 rectangles idea is interesting, but it's kind of complicated to keep rendering each time... is the mask thing feasible?

Comment: Proper rendering is done each frame, and the mask would require that also. (Keeping the old frames can result in rendering garbage upon changing it.)